# Is simultaneous video output from mainboard and graphics card possible?

Tags: linux, video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

Is it possible to get (coherent desktop) video output on the graphics card and the motherboard at the same time?

If so, how? 
If not, why? What would have to change for it to be possible?

So far, it seems to me it is not possible as my system does not seem to detect any connections on the motherboard video output ports while outputting on the graphics card although they are listed (as disconnected by `xrandr`).

Comment: Many main boards disable on board graphics when a gpu card is installed, some have a bios setting to enable both, some do not. More information is needed... What computer or mainboard?

Comment: @acejavelin I am using an [ASUS F2A85-V](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/F2A85V/) with an AMD A10-6800k APU and an NVidia dedicated card. However, my question is more about hardware/software constellations that make this possible at all and only a tiny bit about whether this is possible on my system (as it is bound to change).

Comment: It is a setting in BIOS although it isn't clear in the owner's manual, look in Advanced - NB Settings, change Integrated Graphics from Auto to Forced should work.

Comment: @acejavelin: I don't see any change after setting this to `Forced`.

Comment: Then you probably can't use both integrated graphics and a PCIE card on that motherboard. If there is no option in BIOS and both do not show up in device manager, then you can't do anything.